# GAE Search API. Obtain total amount of matching documents

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, gae-search

Hi,
I am using GAE Search API, and it seems to be a really great feature, which by the way adds so vital functionality lacked in standard datastore queries.
But i have faced a problem to implement a standard pagination, namely to get a total amount of matching the query documents. Certainly, i can implement a list with a "show more" button using Cursor, but it would be also great to be able to obtain a total amount.
Any ideas on how to do this?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

set your accuracy

```
QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder()
        ...set other options
        .setNumberFoundAccuracy(1000);
        .build();
```

> Sets the accuracy requirement for Results.getNumberFound(). If set,
>   getNumberFound() will be accurate up to at least that number. For
>   example, when set to 100, any getNumberFound() <= 100 is accurate.
>   This option may add considerable latency / expense, especially when
>   used with setFieldsToReturn(String...).

Step 2 run query

```
 Query query = Query.newBuilder().setOptions(options).build(queryString);
 Results<ScoredDocument> results = getIndex().search(query);
```

Step 3 call getNumberFound()

```
 results.getNumberFound();
```

> The number of results found by the search. If the value is less than
>   or equal to the corresponding QueryOptions.getNumberFoundAccuracy(),
>   then it is accurate, otherwise it is an approximation Returns: the
>   number of results found

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! (seems i have inattentively read API javadoc, sorry)